# Laravel Model Object Gets Created Two Times

Tags: php, laravel, class, object, laravel-5

I am creating my model object using `new` keyword. But each time the two objects created. My code is

```
class DashBoardController extends Controller
{
    public static $count=0;
    public function __construct()
    {
        DashBoardController::$count++;
    }

    public function dashboard(Request $request)
    {
        $obj = new DashBoardController();
        echo DashBoardController::$count;
    }
}
```

It gives me output as

> O/P: 2

Comment: you get your output from the `dashboard()` function right? in that case, it's because you make a new instance again before echoing the count. So it increments you `$count` property twice.

Comment: @FMashiro I edited my question, actually that class extends controller, but here i am creating only one object using new, so constructor should be called only one time and count get increased to 1 only

Comment: so, if I get this correctly, all you do is: 
`$dashboard = new DashBoardController();
 echo $dashboard::$count;
` 
and that returns 2??

Comment: @FMashiro yes, $count is a static variable so i just called it with class name

Comment: but I mean, is that the only content of your script? Make a test file that contains only that and your class just to make sure, it could have been called somewhere else.

Comment: In a single file it works fine(without extend), but here it gives count as 2

Comment: then it means that it also gets instantiated somewhere else. My guess is that you call the `dashboard` method somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The result is right, there are two instances of DashboardController: The one created by the routing and then the one created by the dashboard method.
It seems that it's better yo use $this instead of creating a new instance of a controller.

Inside the dashboard method you are inside an already existing controller!